# Which database should i use to sotre data from C# desktop application and retrieve it in android app?

Tags: android, database, c#

I am going to do a final year project in which I'll have to store data in a database from a C# desktop application and then I'll have to retrieve that data in an android app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would store it on a server (I like MySql) and access that from both – write from C#, read from Android.

If you are asking about a database which can be used by both and copied from the desktop to Android, then I would recommend [Sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html) where the database is a single file which you can copy.

Comment: What did you choose?

Comment: I went with MySql